# SFINAE for class member function (one compiles the other not)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

Why is `class A` compiling and `class B` not compiling, where the compiler complains about having two declarations, are not both relying on SFINAE? 
Both should actually use template type deduction when using `foo`?

So the question really is, whats the subtle different in these two version 
and why is `class A` successfully using sfinae...?

- Class A uses a **value-defaulted** (zero) *annonymous* (not necessary) **non-type**
  template parameter
- Class B uses a **type-defaulted** (with enable_if) *annonymous* **type** template parameter

The code:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{

    template<typename U, 
             typename std::enable_if<!std::is_floating_point<U>::value>::type * = nullptr
            >
    void foo() {}

    template<typename U, 
             typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value>::type * = nullptr
            >
    void foo() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct B
{

    template<typename U, 
             typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_floating_point<U>::value>::type
            >
    void foo() {}

    template<typename U, 
             typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value>::type
            >
    void foo() {}
};
```

Live code at: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40ec5efc7ba2a47c

Comment: I made some error, for those who use this as a reference:
corrected to non-type (void *) pointer!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

§1.3.22 defines the signature of a function template:

> **signature**  
>  `<`class member function template`>` name, parameter type list (8.3.5), class of which the function is a member,
>   cv-qualifiers (if any), ref-qualifier (if any), return type, and
>   template parameter list

The template parameter list does not include the default arguments given. For `A::foo`, the template parameters are not equivalent (a term precisely defined in §14.5.6.1). In `B::foo`, they are. You're simply declaring the same function template with different default arguments - and thereby violate both §9.2/1 and §14.1/12.

This is a common problem when overloading function templates solely by a condition for `enable_if`. In particular for constructors, where you can't place the `enable_if` part in the return value.

Answer (score 3):

In `class B`, both `foo` have same signature (even if they are different default value):

```
template <typename U, typename Dummy>
void foo();
```

So the error for class B.

In class A, the type are literally different (even if they both ends to `void`)

Comment: but isn't the signature different because the annonymous type is different?
or why does that not matter? because it is annonymous type?

Comment: Because it is default value, so not part of the signature as for regular default arguments: `int bar(int=42)` **is** `int bar(int)`.