# Conditionally enable an operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, c++14, type-traits

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
template<class E>
class vector_expression {};

template<class Tuple>
class vector
    : public vector_expression<vector<Tuple>>
{
public:
    using value_type = typename Tuple::value_type;
    using size_type = typename Tuple::size_type;
};

namespace detail
{
    template<class E>
    constexpr bool is_vector_expression_v = std::is_base_of_v<vector_expression<std::decay_t<E>>, std::decay_t<E>>;

    template<class E, class = void>
    struct value_type { using type = std::decay_t<E>; };
    template<class E>
    struct value_type<E, std::enable_if_t<is_vector_expression_v<E>>> { using type = typename std::decay_t<E>::value_type; };

    template<class E>
    using value_type_t = typename value_type<E>::type;

    template<class E1, class E2, class BinaryOperation>
    class vector_binary_operation
    {
    public:
        using value_type = std::result_of_t<BinaryOperation(value_type_t<E1>, value_type_t<E2>)>;
    };
}
```

How can I conditionally enable an `operator[](size_type i)` for `vectory_binary_operation`? The idea is to return ...

- `m_op(m_e1[i], m_e2[i])` iff `m_e1` and `m_e2` are both `vector_expression`s
- `m_op(m_e1, m_e2[i])` iff `m_e1` is not a vector_expression
- `m_op(m_e1[i], m_e2)` iff `m_e2` is not a vector_expression

How can I do that? I've tried to treat the operator as a `template<class F1 = E1, class F2 = E2>` and to use `std::enable_if_t<is_vector_expression_v<F1> && is_vector_expression_v<F2>` (and so on). But that yields the compiler error message *no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration*.

Comment: Please provide full relevant code.

Comment: When you use `class F1 = E1, class F2 = E2` then be consistent, and use `F1` and `F2` as `enable_if` arguments

Comment: @SergeyA The relevant code was exactly the code in the linked question. I thought it would be better to reference it (such that everyone can see that I changed nothing). However, since some people downvoted this question, I've edited the question and copied the code over to this question.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That was just a typo, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on a function or operator, use enable_if this way:

```
template<class A, class B,
         std::enable_if_t<condition_test_here<A,B>::value>* = nullptr>
auto operator+(A, const B&) 
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why `class = std::enable_if_t</* ... */>` is not working, while `std::enable_if_t</* ... */>* = nullptr` is working?

Comment: @0xbadf00d you probably hit [this scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36500292/3953764)

Comment: @0xbadf00d as Piotr says, Yakk explains it beautifully in the link above.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Does it work, if we use the `enable_if` in the return type, i.e. use `template<class F1 = E1, class F2 = E2> std::enable_if_t<is_vector_expression_v<E1> && is_vector_expression_v<E2>, value_type> operator[](size_type i) const;` (and so on)? Or do we encounter the same problem as described by Yakk?

Comment: @0xbadf00d that'll work, precisely because it avoids the duplicate template signature fiasco. However, I use the * = nullptr form in all cases because it also works when return-type substitution cannot - i.e. in constructors.

Comment: The funny thing is that the typo mentioned by @PiotrSkotnicki in his comment below the question was the reason why my code didn't work (I've used the `enable_if` in the return type).

Comment: @0xbadf00d for me that was clear at the very moment of reading the error message you pasted