# C++ function template overload on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Should it be possible to overload function template like this (only on template parameter using enable_if):

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>>
void fn(T t)
{

}
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>>
void fn(T t)
{

}
```

if conditions in `enable_if` don't overlap? My MSVS compiler complains, that `'void fn(T)' : function template has already been defined`. If not, what is the alternative (ideally not putting `enable_if` anywhere else than into template parameters)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36500292/3953764

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default arguments don't play a role in determining uniqueness of functions. So what the compiler sees is that you're defining two functions like:

```
template <class T, class>
void fn(T t) { }

template <class T, class>
void fn(T t) { }
```

That's redefining the same function, hence the error. What you can do instead is make the `enable_if` itself a template non-type parameter:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int> = 0>
void fn(T t) { }


template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int> = 0>
void fn(T t) { }
```

And now we have different signatures, hence different functions. SFINAE will take care of removing one or the other from the overload set as expected.

Comment: Default non-type argument does not count as default argument?

Comment: @Alexander The functions don't differ in the defaults - they differ in the types.

Comment: Ah now I understand. So if you call function with int, in first case it sees template <class T, int> and in second case it sees just <class T>, right?

Comment: @Alexander In the first case, yes. But the second overload would trigger a substitution failure because of `enable_if_t<false>`

Comment: @AlexanderBily In the second case what the compiler would see is <class T, = 0> which is obviously not valid code, so SFINAE kicks it and doesn't throw a compile error.  This happens because the typedef enable_if<T>::type is not defined if the condition is not true.