# Template Parameters and template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am relatively new to C++(14) . And  i am working on enhancing my current knowledge by reading through the official documentation from [cpprefernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)  . I have some questions about template declaration : [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) page gives the following possible parameters(non-type template parameter) in the declarations for a class template .

```
type name(optional) // (1)
```

My question is :
1.)What is meant by `type name` ? I am sure it is not same as `typename` mentioned [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename).

Further on the same [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter) , i see the example :

```
// simple non-type template parameter
template<int N>
struct S { int a[N]; };
```

However from `//1`  ,  i see the type name  is optional , so i hypothesis the below should work but it does not:(Indeed i see the  below declaration `template<N>` can be seen as template argument with type param.) \

```
// simple non-type template parameter
template<N>
struct S { int a[N]; };
```

So where is my understanding/reading of official docs is going wrong ?

Edit :

I tried the following :

```
template< int>
struct S { int a[N]; };
```

which does not compile with the error `'N' was not declared in the scope`.

Comment: The _name_ is optional (the `N`), the _type_ is mandatory (the `int`). But in your code you actually need the name, so you can't omit it.

Comment: Can you give an example , where the name is not given but just the type ? I tried making such an example in the edit , but  does not work either .

Comment: Well, sure. It doesn't work because you actually need the name. This works: `template <int> struct S { };`

Comment: Now i see what you mean . But i see  this declaration , won't solve any purpose . So the official docs just mean , that the declaration is possible ,irrespective of whether it is useful or not ?

Comment: It's useful for forward declarations. `template<int> struct S;`

Comment: Just an aside - cppreference is not an *official* set of docs.   They're very useful though.

Comment: You might be interested by [whats-the-point-of-unnamed-non-type-template-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824884/whats-the-point-of-unnamed-non-type-template-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

For that to work, `N` would need to be a type.

Templates only accept a type followed by an optional name for that type. So for instance this **might** work (though I haven't tried it):

```
template <int> // ...
```

But note that `N` is not declared. If you want to use `N` in your template, you will need to declare `N` like this:

```
template <int N> // ...
```

Here, `N` is declared as an `int`, so you can use it just as you would an `int`.

---

Note: You also have the option of something like this:

```
template <class N> // ...
```

Here `N` becomes a template replacement for a type. It isn't an int as above.

Of course, that's probably not what you want.

Comment: I see the `template <int> struct S { }` works from Barry's comment . But then  i think it does not solve any purpose . From @Kerndog73's answer , i see this can be used in forward declaration of template class . I have never used a forward declaration for template classes though  .  Is there any other use of such declaration ?

Comment: A forward declaration of a template class? I would assume the same reasons you would use a forward declaration in the first place would still apply.