# Is it possible to define both const and regular version of the function with a single definition? (using templates, auto, decltype, etc)

Tags: c++, overloading, constants, template-instantiation

Suppose that I am writing an iterator and const_iterator for singly linked list.

Suppose that I have a following classes:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T value;
    Node* next;
}

template <typename T>
struct NodePtr
{
private:
     Node<T>* node;
public:
     T& operator*() { return node->value; }
     const T& operator*() const { return node->value; }

     // Ommitted increment, comparison and so on...
}

class Iterator<T, bool isConst>
{
     private: NodePtr<T> nodePtr;
     using Reference = std::conditional_t<isConst, const T&, T&>;

     Reference operator*() { return *nodePtr; }
     const Reference operator*() const { return *nodePtr; }

     // Ommited
}
```

My question is whether it is possible somehow to replace the lines

```
Reference operator*() { return node->value; }
const Reference operator*() const { return node->value; }
```

with a single definition (perhaps using the template argument isConst) and have the const specifier deduced by the compiler?
I want to have * to be const T& operator*() const when isConst = true
and have both versions when isConst = false. 
Is it possible? If it is - then how to do it?

Comment: Note that `const Reference` is most probably not what you want. That `const` is the top-level `const`, it won't turn, e.g. `int&` into `const int&`.

Comment: Seems that you are right. But this is weird. Are not references already const? Also, why does it work for regular types but acts "weirdly" when used together with std::conditional_t?

Comment: Consider adding `const` to `int*`. I would expect to get "`const (int*)`", i.e. `int* const`, not `const int*`. Loosely speaking, references are already `const`, that's why top-level `const` is simply ignored for references. All this has nothing to do with `std::conditional_t` itself. With `using T = int&`, `const T` and `T` are both `int&`.

Comment: Makes sense, although counter intuitive. Thanks.

Comment: But note that formally references are non-const, i.e. `std::is_const_v` returns `false` for them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I would not ask this question have I seen it before, however it is not what I have asked. I am interested in not having the function without const qualifier being generated at all, and enable_if is the answer.

Comment: @RazielMagius My bad, didn't fully read the question. Reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to write the function only once. Most things you can do with auto and templates but the problem is the `const` specifier for the function itself. I know of no way to make that in any form conditional. You could make it always const and then the `nodePtr` mutable but that kind of defeats the point of the whole thing. What you can do is deactivate the non-const overload for the `const_iter` by doing the following

```
template<bool tmp = isConst, std::enable_if_t<!tmp, char> = 0> // you need the tmp so that the enable_if is dependent
Reference operator*() {
    return *nodePtr;
}
```

Comment: In C++20 this can be reduced to `Reference operator*() requires (!IsConst) {...}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Visual studio does not support c++20 yet, unfortunately ;-(

Comment: @n314159  I think that std::enable_if_t<!tmp, char> = 0 can be replaced with std::enable_if_t<!tmp> (which is same std::enable_if<!tmp, void>) I think, as the value is not used, and produces less noise. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RazielMagius `std::enable_if_t<!tmp>` will expand to `void` if the condition is true, and `void` is not a valid type for a template parameter. Try it, it won't work (this overload will never be called).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat What about  template<bool tmp = isConst, typename = std::enable_if_t<!tmp> >. In this case it does work, I think.

Comment: @RazielMagius Yeah, because it expands to `typename = void`, and `void` can be passed into a type template parameter. But it can't be a type of a non-type template parameter: `void X` is invalid.

Comment: @RazielMagius in the comments under this question I learned a bit about that topic.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824884/whats-the-point-of-unnamed-non-type-template-parameters?noredirect=1#comment105791006_59824884