# What is this construct : template <int> void funcName(int i)?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, function-templates

I accidentally made a mistake coding a template function specialization, and the resulting construct passed compilation with VS17. ( The third construct in the included code below )

Is this a valid construct?
How would I call this function?

```
template <class T> void tempfunc(T t)
{
    cout << "Generic Template Version\n";
}

template <>
void tempfunc<int>(int i) {
    cout << "Template Specialization Version\n";
}

template <int> void tempfunc(int i)
{
    cout << "Coding Mistake Version\n";
}
```

I have not been able to call the third construct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a valid construct. It's a template overload, that is templated on a non-type template parameter of type `int`.

You can call it like this:

```
tempfunc<42>(42);
```

Note that calls without the template syntax will still call the versions that are templated on a type parameter:

```
tempfunc(42);   // calls specialization
tempfunc(true); // calls primary
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rfPoh1)

Comment: @cigien Thanks for the explanation. While I was familiar with non-type template parameters,  I don't think I had seen an example with the parameter name omitted.

Comment: @GonenI: I never have either. I'm struggling to think of a use for it

Comment: @MooingDuck right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824884/whats-the-point-of-unnamed-non-type-template-parameters

Answer (score 3):

`template` parameters are of two kinds - type parameters and non-type parameters.

When you use

```
template <class T> void tempfunc(T t) { ... }
```

the `template` parameter is a type parameter. To use such a template, the type has to either deduced or explicitly provided.

When you use

```
template <int> void tempfunc(int i) { ... }
```

the `template` parameter is a non-type parameter. As far as I know, the value of a non-type parameter cannot be deduced. It has to be explicitly provided.

The last `template` uses a non-type paramter. The value with which it can be called has to be of type `int`. Example invocations:

```
tempfunc<0>(20);
tempfunc<999>(34);
```

Comment: It's called a "non-type template parameter"