# C++ std::enable_if fallback?

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I'm setting up a variadic template function to be able to call various function overloads on a specific series of classes. So far, I've been able to "break" the compilation when an unsupported class is passed to the function, but I'd like to be able to provide a valid fallback to handle the "unsupported" scenario at runtime.

The current implementation goes like this :

```
struct ClassA {};
struct ClassB {};
struct ClassC {};

template<typename T> struct is_my_class         : std::false_type {};
template<>           struct is_my_class<ClassA> : std::true_type  {};
template<>           struct is_my_class<ClassB> : std::true_type  {};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_my_class_v = is_my_class<T>::value;

void runOverload(ClassA c) { printf("ClassA overload\n"); }
void runOverload(ClassB c) { printf("ClassB overload\n"); }

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_my_class_v<T>>>
void run(T myClass)
{
    runOverload(myClass);
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void run(T myClass, Ts... classesLeft)
{
    run(myClass);
    run(classesLeft...);
};

int main()
{
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b;
    ClassC c;

    run(a, b); // works
    run(c);    // does not compile
}
```

Here, the two most promising (but still failing) attempts I've made to have a fallback for `run`:

1 - Adding a simple `!` in front of `is_my_class<T>`, giving me the following error : `error C2995: 'void run(T)': function template has already been defined`

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_my_class_v<T>>>
void run(T myClass)
{
    printf("Not supported\n");
};
```

2 - Making a more "primary" template definition, which yields a sad but obvious : `error C2668: 'run': ambiguous call to overloaded function`

```
template<typename T>
void run(T myClass)
{
    printf("Not supported\n");
};
```

**EDIT**
I forgot to specify I was looking for a solution also compatible with C++11/14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I'd recommend @cigien 's solution if c++17 is avaiable, I would like to add, that the ambiguity problem can be mitigated pre c++17 by changing the type of the `enable_if` template argument, and hence changing the signature of the "fallback function". The following code should work fine:

```cpp
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_my_class_v<T>, int> = 0> 
//template<typename T>
void run(T myClass) {
  printf("error\n");
};
```

Full code available on [CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/25PByX), tested on GCC and Clang trunk.

I'd also like to add, that in all use cases I can imagine, it is better to have a compile time error (which you could for instance achieve by using a `static assertion` instead of `SFINAE`).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499008/sfinae-works-differently-in-cases-of-type-and-non-type-template-parameters) you can read about why the function delcaration is not ambiguous, even when using two "ints" as template arguments.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `= 0` at the end of the template parameters?

Comment: This defaults the integer typed template to a value (which is zero in this case). You do more or less the same with your enable_if type, there you default a typename to the type contained in the enable_if

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid `enable_if` entirely, and just use a compile-time `if` to to decide what code to execute:

```
template<typename T>
void run(T myClass)
{
  if constexpr (is_my_class_v<T>)
    runOverload(myClass);
  else
    printf("Not supported\n"); 
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/2pT8Jf).

Comment: I guess I would need something like std::conjunction to handle the variadic version?

Comment: No, the variadic version stays the same. Which branch of the `constexpr` is take is decided at compile time, same as the variadic expansion. Added a demo.

Comment: `if constexpr ()` is C++17 right? Any suggestion for a backward-compatible solution?

Comment: Yes, go ahead and add the tag for the language version you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote following code and it works. I think you just messed up with syntax of SFINAE.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct ClassA {};
struct ClassB {};
struct ClassC {};

template<typename T> struct is_my_class         : std::false_type {};
template<>           struct is_my_class<ClassA> : std::true_type  {};
template<>           struct is_my_class<ClassB> : std::true_type  {};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_my_class_v = is_my_class<T>::value;

void runOverload(ClassA c) { printf("ClassA overload\n"); }
void runOverload(ClassB c) { printf("ClassB overload\n"); }

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_my_class_v<T>,int> = 0>
void run(T myClass)
{
    runOverload(myClass);
};

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<not is_my_class_v<T>,int> = 0>
void run(T myClass)
{
    printf("Not supported\n");
};

// wrote an extra SFINEA here to ensure that Ts aren't empty - else it might be an ODR issue despite the fact that it compiles
template<typename T, typename... Ts, std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) != 0,int> = 0>
void run(T myClass, Ts... classesLeft)
{
    run(myClass);
    run(classesLeft...);
};

int main()
{
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b;
    ClassC c;

    run(a, b);
    run(c);
}
```

It prints

> ClassA overload
>   ClassB overload
>   Not supported

Comment: This works, but the problem with the ambiguity is due to the fact that the template argument from enable_if is a type in the OP's code, which is fixed in your and my answer by changing it to an `int`.  The ambiguity is only due to the variadic overload, and in normally not a problem when using SFINAE.

Comment: @mutableVoid I believe SFINEA's purpose is also in resolving overloads. If one method doesn't enable it then it's simply better to use the one that does. No? Unless one explicitly wants to disable overloads (though, it doesn't actually work properly).

Comment: Sure, I think my comment might have been somewhat unclear, I just wanted to point out, that the syntax of SFINAE which the OP used is usually fine, and that in this case it is not possible to use a type as the template argument used in enable_if because it is ambiguous. However, I have to point out, that I was wrong in my assessment of the reason for the ambiguity: It turns out, that the original code is still considered ambiguous if the variadic function is commented out.

Comment: BTW, I found the reason for the ambiguity, the cause for one solution being ambiguous and one not is listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499008/sfinae-works-differently-in-cases-of-type-and-non-type-template-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Have a fallback `runOverload` template

```
template<typename T>
void runOverload(T myClass)
{
    printf("Not supported\n");
};
```